# eBay API findItemsAdvanced call ignores categoryID

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

Any attempt to make an eBay API call to `findItemsAdvanced` is ignoring the `categoryID` parameter.

For example, I want to find all auctions matching "1943" in the "Video Games" category (ID #1249). eBay instead returns a bunch of auctions for coins instead.

This is the URL I am using:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=AppID&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&keywords=1943&categoryid=1249
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:** I was using "categoryid" instead of "categoryId." (sigh)